# How to initialize IIS web app's Physical Path Credentials property in WiX

Tags: iis-7, wix, wix3.5, wix-extension

*Update: probably an IIS or MSI version dependency*

The issue appears on this configuration:

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Version 6.1 (build 7600), IIS 7.5.7600.16385, MSI v5.0.7600.16385

On this second configuration the same MSI works pretty fine:

Vista Enterprise SP2, IIS 7.0.6000.16386, MSI v4.5.6002.18005

*Original question:*

I have created WiX installer package for the new project I am working on and have a little unresolved issue related to proper registering the web application into IIS7.

The problem is that my web application is registered with incorrect Physical Path credentials property value (this property can be accessed through IIS7 by focusing the web app node and then opening its Advanced settings dialog box). After installation of my application the value is set to a 'specific user' with username 'name'. Such user of course does not exist in my environment, which causes the web app to fail on 500.19 when trying to open it in the browser.

So, after installing the app I have to open IIS and reset the Physical Path Credentials property to 'application user (pass-through authentication)', in order to force the web app to access its virtual directory using application pool's identity. This manual change of that property solves the problem..

Does anyone know how to change WiX behavior, so that Physical Path Credentials is set to 'application user' right out-from-the-box without any need to manually repair the value?

This is the fragment I use for configuring the IIS part of my solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension"
      xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

  <Fragment>
    <!-- Install to default web site -->
    <iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description='Default Web Site'>
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
    </iis:WebSite>

    <DirectoryRef Id="WebSiteContentDir">
      <!-- Configuring app pool -->
      <Component Id="ApplicationPoolComponent" Guid="{MY-GUID}" KeyPath="yes">
        <util:User Id="ApplicationPoolUser" CreateUser="no"
               Domain="MYDOMAIN" Name="MYUSER"
               Password="MYPWD" />

        <iis:WebAppPool Id="ApplicationPool" Name="MyApp" Identity="other" User="ApplicationPoolUser"
                    ManagedPipelineMode="classic" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
      </Component>

      <!-- Configuring virtual dir -->
      <Component Id="VirtualDirComponent" Guid="{MY-GUID}" KeyPath="yes" >
        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VirtualDir" Alias="MyApp" Directory="WebSiteContentDir" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
          <iis:WebDirProperties Id="VirtualDirProperties" WindowsAuthentication="yes" />
          <iis:WebApplication Id="WebApplication" Name="MyApp" WebAppPool="ApplicationPool" />
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>        
      </Component>

    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Ww have already run into this issue on other projects and always solved using a powershell script fixing that property value that was executed automatically during the installation. I believe there must be a way to make WiX install it the requested way and hope to find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds very similar to the following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241272/how-to-specify-the-apppool-identity-in-a-wix-permission-element/7243095#7243095. Check the solution proposed there.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Thanks Yan for the link. As far as I understand it, this is not soution to my issue, because the app pool identity is set correctly in my case and there is no problem regarding app pool identity access rights to the folder. My problem is that virtual directory is configured NOT to use app pool identity for accessing the underlying folder and instead of that use another identity (user account called 'name'), which does not exist in my environment. So the issue appears not on app pool properties but on virtual dir (or application itself) properties in IIS...

Comment: Have you tried it? :-) It might seem unrelated, but you actually expect the user you create in your installation to be set as that identity in IIS. I would still suggest you follow the second point in the answer I referenced - schedule SchedSecureObjects action after ConfigureIIs action and see if there's any effect.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko There is no SchedSecureObjects action in my MSI... I am looking into through Orca to CustomAction table content, is that the place where that action should appear? Anyway, I still think we do not understand each other. My installation is NOT creating any user account in my environment. It already exists and has all necessary access rights. All I need is to tell IIS that this account is supposed to be used as app pool's identity (no problem, works fine) and that I also want the same identity to be used to access the virtual folder physical path (this point only does not work).

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry for misunderstanding. In this case, I doubt that WiX IIS extension has anything for you out of the box. You'll have to run a custom action (e.g. call appcmd with proper parameters) to accomplish this.