# Permission set for newly created IIS AppPool Identity

Tags: iis-7, permissions, wix

I need to set permissions on logs folder for created IIS Application Pool. The code to set permissions:

```
<CreateFolder Directory="SiteLogsFolder">
    <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" Read="yes" GenericRead="yes"/>
    <util:PermissionEx User="[IisSiteUser]" GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes" GenericExecute="yes" Delete="yes" DeleteChild="yes"/>
</CreateFolder>

<CustomAction Id="SetIis6SiteUser" Property="IisSiteUser" Value="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"/>
<CustomAction Id="SetIis7SiteUser" Property="IisSiteUser" Value="IIS AppPool\[SITE_APP_POOL]"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetIis7SiteUser" Before="InstallInitialize">IISMAJORVERSION>="#7"</Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetIis6SiteUser" Before="InstallInitialize">IISMAJORVERSION="#6"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This works fine for IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003, but fails for IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008. I get the error:

```
ExecSecureObjects:  Error 0x80070534: failed to get sid for account: IIS AppPool\MyAppPool
```

**Investigation details:**

- I tried also "IIS APPPOOL" domain - same result.
- Also tried setting both Domain and User properties of PermissionEx element instead of merging them in User attribute. Again same error.
- Using active directory accounts in PermissionEx works fine. Also active directory account works fine with IIS site pool when set.
- If I try to set permissions for another AppPool (not the creating by my installer one, for example IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool), again all works fine. The problem occurs only when I set permissions for AppPool, that is created by my installer.
- I checked sequencing of the ConfigureIIs, SchedSecureObjects and ExecSecureObjects and tried to force ConfigureIIs execute before the two others (it was recommended [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241272/how-to-specify-the-apppool-identity-in-a-wix-permission-element)). Unfortunately that didn't help as well.

Comment: same problem here, looking for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I was building my WIX project as x86. I solved it by scheduling SchedSecureObjects and ExecSecureObjects before ConfigureIIs.

```
<Custom Action="SchedSecureObjects" After="ConfigureIIs" />
<Custom Action="ExecSecureObjects" After="ConfigureIIs" />
```

The problem came up again when I started building the project as x64. This time I had to schedule the 64 bit actions before ConfigureIIs as well.

```
<Custom Action="SchedSecureObjects_x64" After="ConfigureIIs" />
<Custom Action="ExecSecureObjects_64" After="ConfigureIIs" />
<Custom Action="SchedSecureObjects" After="ConfigureIIs" />
<Custom Action="ExecSecureObjects" After="ConfigureIIs" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Testing on Server 2012, I confirmed that there can be a delay before the account becomes available.  Using the following script, I repro'd a failure to find in 3 of about 30 attempts.  It seems that we will need a delay between creation of the app pool and looking up the SID.  In my test, it never took more than 1s.

```
param ($id)
if (!$id) {write-host "specify an id"; return}
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /name:$id /managedRuntimeVersion:"v4.0" /managedPipelineMode:"Integrated"
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("IIS APPPOOL\$id")
$sid=""
while (!$sid)
{
  $sid = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
  if (!$sid) {write-host "$id not found"} else {$sid}
  sleep 1
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea when you are writing a script. But it's not so easy to suspend Windows installer exactly between creation of user identity and using it - it does all operations in internally defined order. It might be possible to create a delay custom action, but that solution would be very awkward