# Executing SQLStrings after ApplicationPool is created WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I need to add a user to my DataBase for `IIS AppPool\MyAppPool`. I need to execute simple query

```
CREATE LOGIN [IIS AppPool\MyAppPool] FROM WINDOWS
```

I use `<sql:SQLString>` element in WiX.
I use `<iis:WebAppPool>` extension to create ApplicationPool.

But Application Pool is created **after** SQL strings have been executed so I got error `"User or group doesn't exist"` from SQL Server.

Is it possible to execute SQL strings after ApplicationPool creation? Or maybe it is possible to sequence `ExecuteSqlStrings` manually?

It is strange, but if I add my own custom action (which calls `sqlcmd.exe` and executes the query) after `ConfigureIIs`, everything works fine. But I don't like such a solution, I suppose using  and etc. is better solution.

Comment: This [answers the similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241272/how-to-specify-the-apppool-identity-in-a-wix-permission-element/7243095#7243095). The idea is to schedule something after `ConfigureIIs` action. In your case it is `ExecuteSqlStrings`

Comment: If I shedule ExecuteSqlStrings manually using
<Custom Action="ExecuteSqlStrings" After="ConfigureIIs"> it exucutes twice.

Comment: No, you just change the sequence of actions, and nothing more. It literally "executes" twice because of its nature as a **deferred** custom action. The first time it is just added to the installation script which is to run on a deferred stage, and the second time it actually does the job.

Comment: BTW, does the error go away when you schedule `ExecuteSqlStrings` after `ConfigureIIs`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't go away.
Maybe this account (IIS AppPool\MyAppPool) is created later, because at the moment when error occurs there is no such account.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and attempted to schedule ExecuteSqlStrings after ConfigureIIs to no avail.  I searched around in some old installers we had made and managed to find one that needed to accomplish the same thing.  Instead of scheduling ExecuteSqlStrings, it scheduled InstallSqlData after ConfigureIIs.  Tried that instead (1), and now the install works correctly.  I don't know the specifics of what's different between InstallSQLData and ExecuteSqlStrings (logically you would think you need to use the latter), but this worked for me and hopefully works for you too.